# Only show one image when displaying image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to show a preview of an image URL.

```
<input name="input_19" id="input_2_19" type="text" value="" class="medium" placeholder="http://" aria-invalid="false">
<script> 


 jQuery('#input_2_19').blur(function() {
    var src = jQuery(this).val();

var previews =  jQuery(".previewImage");
var drawPreview = true;

var PreviousSource =  jQuery(this).data('previousSource');

if(!src.match("^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$") && src != "")
{
      jQuery("#warning").html("Must be an image");
      return false;  
} else {
     jQuery("#warning").html("");
}

 jQuery.each(previews , function(index, value) { 
    if (src == "" && PreviousSource == $(value).attr('src'))
    {
          jQuery(value).remove();
         drawPreview = false;
         return false; 
    }
    if( jQuery(value).attr('src') == src)
    {
        drawPreview = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if(drawPreview) {
     jQuery('#prev').append('<img class="previewImage" style="max-width:500px;" src="' + src + '">');   
}
var previousSource =  jQuery(this).data('previousSource', src);
});
</script>

<div id="warning"></div>
<div id="prev"></div>
```

It works well, but if I change the image URL then the second image will show up too and the first will stay. 
How do I make it so only one image preview is shown? 
https://jsfiddle.net/LucyTech/qohxryL4/4/

Also why doesn't it work with some images eg
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1q0ucSYrpK1RjSZTEq6AWAVXap/Mifa-Portable-Bluetooth-speaker-Portable-Wireless-Loudspeaker-Sound-System-10W-stereo-Music-surround-Waterproof-Outdoor-Speaker.jpg
what is wrong with this url? In the browser it shows an image so why does the code give an error?

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/q9yzj1ok/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this javascript. That will give you result as per your expectation.

```
$('#input_2_19').blur(function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).val());

    var src = jQuery(this).val();

    var previews = $(".previewImage");
    var drawPreview = true;

    var PreviousSource = $(this).data('previousSource');

    if(src.match("/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/") != null && src != "")
    {
         $("#warning").html("Must be an image");
          return false;  
    } else {
        $("#warning").html("");
        $('#prev').html('<img class="previewImage" style="max-width:50px;" src="' + src + '">');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using append() will always add a new element. Maybe you should include the img tag in the initial html with its own id property and change its src property with attr(). You can use show() and hide() on an image element or you can wrap it in a div/span and hide this one.

Answer (score 0):

Before appending the

below code should work.

```
jQuery('#prev').html('');
```

After this add your img tag

```
jQuery('#prev').html('<img class="previewImage" style="max-width:500px;" src="' + src + '">');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the image not previewing for some the links I think is related to the regular expression that you wrote in `the str.math` I am not very good in so I can not help you with it but I took a look at your post's first comment "Jinesh", his/her regular expression seems to work. For the other problem, I wrote some piece of code for with comments to fix the the multiple image

```js
// When you release the keyboard key
$("#urlInput").keyup(function(){
  $("#warning").text(""); // Clear message div
  var url = $("#urlInput").val(); // get url in the input box
  if(isValidImageUrl(url)) // Validate the url
    $("#prevImg").attr("src", url).show(); // Change src of th eimg tag and Show it
  else
    $("#prevImg").attr("src", "").hide(); // If the url is not valid, hide the img tag in the html
});

// When you get out the side the input box such as clicking outside or pressing tab key
$("#urlInput").blur(function(){
  var url = $("#urlInput").val(); // Get the url in the input box
  if(!isValidImageUrl(url)) // Validate the url
    $("#warning").text("Must be an image"); // if the url is invalid show warning
});

// Valdiate url fucntion
function isValidImageUrl(checkUrl){
   return checkUrl.match("^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,10000}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$");
}
```

```css
img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="warning"></div>

<input id="urlInput">
<div id="prev">
  <img id="prevImg">
</div>
```